# AngularJS Service returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have the following service:

```
app.services.emailService = ['$http', '$sce', function ($http, $sce) {

    return {
        getMessage: function(messageId, callback) {
            $http.get('/api/email/inbox' + '/' + messageId).then(function(response) {
                response.data.message.updated_at = new Date(response.data.message.updated_at.replace(/-/g,"/"));
                response.data.message.body = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.message.body);
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };

}];
```

In my controller I am assigning the return value to a `$scope.message` var so that I can display in the front end.

`$scope.message` is undefined

```
$scope.getMessage = function(messageId) {
        $scope.message = emailService.getMessage($scope.messages[messageId].id);
        console.log($scope.message);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function getMessage has no return statement. But [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is asynchronous so it will return a [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

```
app.services.emailService = ['$http', '$sce', function ($http, $sce) {

    return {
        getMessage: function(messageId, callback) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http
                .get('/api/email/inbox' + '/' + messageId)
                .then(function () {
                    response.data.message.updated_at = new Date(response.data.message.updated_at.replace(/-/g,"/"));
                    response.data.message.body = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.message.body);
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                })
                .catch(function (e) {
                    deferred.reject(e);
                );
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };

}];
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.getMessage = function(messageId) {
    emailService
        .getMessage($scope.messages[messageId].id)
        .then(function (message) {
            $scope.message = message;
            console.log(message);
        });
}
```

If you want to clean your response in emailService you need to declare a promises by yourself.

Comment: Cool! This works, but I did have a return response.data in the service, also, should I keep as much logic in my service rather than the controller? Slim controllers and all that? Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I would recommend to keep all the logic in your service yes. I updated my answer to be do that it is way better this way ;)